# Why is an int in a list and in an compact array the same size? (24bytes)

Tags: python, arrays

I was just reading that a compactArray defined as "i" should yield an array that hold integers with 2 or 4 bytes, but executing this snippet i am still getting 24bytes, which is the same as i would use integer lists.

```
import array
import sys
lowLevelArray = array.array("i", [1,2,3])
print sys.getsizeof(lowLevelArray[0])
pythonList = [1,2,3]
print sys.getsizeof(pythonList[0])
```

Output:

> 24
>
> 24

Comment: Are you trying to point out, that python is reserving extra memory when creating an element? but this would only effect the list size....or do you mean something else ? can you elaborate itemseize more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array object *is* more space efficient; it's 4 bytes per int it holds, plus 56 bytes overhead:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(array.array("i", [1,2,3])
68L
>>> sys.getsizeof(array.array("i", range(1000))
4056L
```

However, when you do

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(lowLevelArray[0])
```

it first evaluates `lowLevelArray[0]`, which of course returns a normal integer, and then shows the size used by *that*. Which is completely unrelated to the fact that you also have an array that happens to hold the same value.

Answer (score 2):

Because once you retrieve the integer it has to be wrapped in a python object so you can work with it. Everything in python is an object, it has no concept of primitives (even though the underlying implementation uses them).

Comment: So what is the benefit of using plain arrays?

Comment: Because the underlying implementation of the array can store the values compactly. You just can't directly access these values. It's useful for serialisation mostly. But it does reduce overall memory usage. That is, when you only access one value at a time the memory usage will be number of ints times 4 bytes + 1 python int. Whereas, the python list will use number of ints times by memory used by python int + number of ints times by space required to store an object in a list (size of object pointer).

Comment: Thanks for the great comment